# Bukkit: Change EXP_Bottle item material to consume instead of throwable

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to build a bukkit plugin to store XP Levels in a EXP_Bottle.
EXP_Bottle is throwable and releases EXP orbs.

I wanted to make it consumable instead of throwable.

Also, I wanted to get the right event on crafting to remove the EXP after the player grabs the new flask instead of when he places all stuff in the crafting table.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe it is possible to change the exp bottle to a consumable as the minecraft client will still think it is a exp bottle.  However, you could listening for [PlayerInteractEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerInteractEvent.html) and achieve a similar functionality. Example:

```
@EventHandler
public void interact(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    ItemStack itemStack = e.getItem();
    // Check to see if the item is a exp bottle
    if (itemStack != null && e.getItem().getType().equals(Material.EXP_BOTTLE)) {
        // Cancel the event so it will not be thrown
        e.setCancelled(true);

        Player player = e.getPlayer();

        // Add exp to the player
        player.giveExp(1);

        // Remove the bottle from the players hand
        int newAmount = e.getItem().getAmount() - 1;
        if (newAmount > 0)
            player.getItemInHand().setAmount(newAmount);
        else
            player.setItemInHand(null);
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to listen for when an item is crafted you can use [CraftItemEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/inventory/CraftItemEvent.html).

Cheers!

Comment: It does work, but I have two weird behaviors:
1- On the last item, it dissapears, but if I use any other item after it, it gets one item again in the same inventory slot.
2- If I leave and rejoin the server I can't consume the items I created correctly. In this instance it throws the bottle to the ground as a normal EXP_Bottle would.

Comment: Herm... I am unable to replicate either of these bugs, I did find one that will throw a [NPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) (I edited my post and fixed it). The first one makes me think you have "ghosted Items" which means the client and server disagree on a item. And for the second try adding some debug messages, make sure the event is being called, make sure that the event is being cancelled etc. Good luck, Cheers!

Comment: Do you think that the "Ghost" thingy could be affected by the Priority?

Comment: Nope, minecraft is single threaded (mostly) and bukkit calls event priorities consecutively.  Priorities are there only if you need your listener called before/after a different listener listening to the same event.  So, if there are no other listeners for that event it does not matter.  (Someone correct me if I am wrong!)